# WSO2 ESB How to send an email from a JMS message to a custom email address?

Tags: email, jms, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm wondering if someone can help me with the following setup.

I want to send a message from my application via JMS to WSO2 ESB so the ESB can send it as en email. I'm using ActiveMQ as queue. Until now, when I send a message via the ActiveMQ interface to the queue, wso2 esb gets it. Then, wso2 esb send the message as email to a specific email address.

So I could configure ActiveMQ and WSO2 esb to send the JMS message to a specific email address (eg. specificaddress@test.com).

And here is my question. How can I modify the receiver address for the email? In the ESB sequence configuration, I currently use a specific address. But the address is dependant on the user that uses my application. So I have to change the "To" property, dependant on the user that has to receive the email.

So how can I pass the values for the properties "To", but also for "Subject", through a JMS message to WSO2 esb sequence?

That's the configuration of the sequence I have:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="sendMail">
   <property name="messageType" value="text/html" scope="axis2" type="STRING"></property>
   <property name="ContentType" value="text/html" scope="axis2"></property>
   <property name="Subject" value="This is the subject." scope="transport"></property>
   <property name="To" value="specificaddress@test.com" scope="transport"></property>
   <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"></property>
   <log level="full"></log>
   <send>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="mailto:"></address>
      </endpoint>
   </send>
</sequence>
```

And this is my proxy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
      name="sendToMailIn"
      transports="jms"
      statistics="disable"
      trace="disable"
      startOnLoad="true">
   <target inSequence="sendMail"/>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

I hope someone has a clue.

***UPDATE***

I think I have the solution!!! Wow :-) Maybe, at first, I was stupid, but here it is ...

What you can do is sending a SOAP envelop through a JMS message to WSO2 ESB. And then, with an XPath expression, you can get the passed values. A little bit has to changed at the proxy and the sequence.

This is the new sequence:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="sendMail">
   <property name="messageType" value="text/html" scope="axis2" type="STRING"></property>
   <property name="ContentType" value="text/html" scope="axis2"></property>
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="Subject" expression="$body/subject" scope="transport"></property>
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="To" expression="$body/to" scope="transport"></property>
   <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"></property>
   <log level="full"></log>
   <send>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="mailto:"></address>
      </endpoint>
   </send>
</sequence>
```

And this is the new proxy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="sendToMailIn"
       transports="jms"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target inSequence="sendMail"/>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
      <rules>
         <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>
         <default>text/xml</default>
      </rules>
   </parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

And this was my SOAP Envelop that WSO2 ESB receives from my ActiMQ queue as JMS message:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org   /soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
    <subject>Email subject comes here.</subject>
    <to>address@test.com</to>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have couple of options here.

1. you can use http headers and send the "to", "subject" values to ESB.
2. Send it as a payload value and extract using XPath expression

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with using JSON in a JMS message. Here is my setup that works for me.

This is my JSON message:

```
{"to":"mail@test.com","subject":"TestSubject","mailbody":"Some body text ..."}
```

This is my proxy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="sendToMailIn"
       transports="jms"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target inSequence="sendMail"/>
   <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
      <rules>
         <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>
         <default>application/json</default>
      </rules>
   </parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.mail.ContentType">application/xml</parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

And this is my sequence:

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="sendMail">
   <property name="messageType" value="text/plain" scope="axis2" type="STRING"></property>
   <property name="ContentType" value="text/plain" scope="axis2"></property>
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="Subject" expression="json-eval($.subject)" scope="transport"></property>
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="To" expression="json-eval($.to)" scope="transport"></property>
   <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"></property>
   <script language="js">
      <![CDATA[var mailbody = mc.getPayloadJSON().mailbody.toString();    mc.setPayloadXML(                           
     <ns:text xmlns:ns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">{mailbody}</ns:text>);]]>
   </script>
   <log level="full"></log>
   <send>
     <endpoint>
        <address uri="mailto:"></address>
     </endpoint>
   </send>
</sequence>
```